# App for virtual keyboard for Windows

Tags: keyboard, windows

I am looking for an Android app which provides a virtual keyboard (and mouse) for a Windows PC. These are my requirements:

- run in window-less mode, e.g. as a service (nice for HTPC)
- provide support for special keys and key combinations

What I tried so far:

[RemoteDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.joshsera)

- [does not run as service](http://code.google.com/p/remotedroid/issues/detail?id=8)
- does not support special keys and key combinations
- does not display any connection information

[AndroMouse](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.iandrobot.andromouse)

- always displays window (does not run as service)

[Gmote](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.gmote.client.android)

- runs as service
- no support for key combinations, just translates the usual android keyboard
- up/down/left/right keys not working

[Mouse and Keyboard Remote](http://www.appbrain.com/app/mouse-keyboard-remote/com.steppschuh.remoteinput)

- no service, but CurrentVersion/Run

Does anyone have another suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally settled with [Unified Remote](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.Relmtech.Remote). It does not provide a real service but can be run without displaying a window as a task bar program. It provides all special key combinations needed and also has a working automatic server detection. And I even haven't tried all the supplied program remotes!

Answer (score 0):

I've been satisfied with [All In One Remote](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.allinoneremote&hl=en) so far. It also works with other OSes than Windows. As for `run in window-less mode`, I can think of a couple of ways to easily hide the server window for All In One Remote. It would just take a few minutes to make in AutoIt. As for `provide support for special keys and key combinations`, as far as I know, I can do key combinations with it too.